# Isomorphic words

Tags: java, file, hashmap

Interview question - A map based design for implementing a code to check for isomorphic words in a file. Efficient approach.

`Two words are called isomorphic if the letters in one word can be remapped to get the second word.`

If there are n words then the best approach I can think of is O(n ^2 log n) time complexity (n words - sort the word - n log n - and store in a hashmap - space complexity O(n)).

If the file is huge then we can load half of it at a time.

Comment: I'm not sure where the log N comes from

Comment: You are sorting the letters of the words, not the words themselves. N words of M chars long on average makes O( N * M * log(M))

Comment: You can use a bitset rather than a hashmap, O(N/8) space

Answer (score 1):

You can map each letter to a prime number, take each word and find the product of it's letters then check to see which words compose the same factorization.

This requires 1 multiplication per letter, and 1 insert for each word into a product map.

Comment: Only problem is integer arithmetic will overflow for long words

Comment: well hashing on tuples of length epsilon where epsilon is the number of letters in the alphabet and the values in each position indicate the number of a particular letter is also an option...

Comment: So using base 26, which means 64 bits of hash  can hold max 12 character words...

Answer (score 1):

We iterate over file, and sort characters in every word using counting sort, then insert sorted word to set. Total Complexity: O(26*n) ~ O(n).

Comment: Where did you get log N

Comment: OOps, sorry, i don't know where :)